# How to apply max to a list of values with predefined order in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I need to apply the max operator to the following list

```
[Tier20 Tier10 Tier30]
```

And it should give me

```
Tier30
```

The predefined ordered list (from low to high) is

```
[Tier5 Tier10 Tier20 Tier30 Tier40 Tier50]
```

What's the best way to achieve this in Clojure?

Comment: If the list is ordered why you need max? use (last coll) and the cost will be O(1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first define the ordering:

```
user> (def order '[Tier5 Tier10 Tier20 Tier30 Tier40 Tier50])
#'user/order
```

then we map the order onto something that can be sorted by creating a `map`

```
user> (def order-map (zipmap order (range)))
{Tier50 5, Tier40 4, Tier30 3, Tier20 2, Tier10 1, Tier5 0}
```

**use the order-map to reduce the input** if all you need is the max/min:

```
user> (reduce #(if (< (order-map %1) (order-map %2)) %1 %2) 
              '[Tier20 Tier10 Tier30])
Tier30
```

---

or if you need the full ordering then use the sort-by function, which is like the regular sort function except it gives you a chance to translate the input before comparison:

```
user> (sort-by (zipmap order (range)) '[Tier20 Tier10 Tier30])
(Tier10 Tier20 Tier30)
```

if you need to modify this map a lot and not re-sort it each time then use a `sorted-set-by` datastructure to store your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Use reduce. For instance, to find the maximum of a list L, you would do:

```
(reduce max L)
```

The real question here is if your Tiers are strings or more complex objects, as it isn't completely clear from your post.  Either way, you can replace max with a lambda expression to pull out the numeric part of the string, like so:

```
(reduce (fn [x y] ...) L)
```

Where ... will be the expression that extracts the numeric portion out of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've just tried. The main point of leverage is the instance method `.indexOf` on `clojure.lang.Vector`.

```
user> (def x ['Tier5 'Tier10 'Tier20 'Tier30 'Tier40 'Tier50])
#'user/x
user> (index-of x 'Tier10)
; Evaluation aborted.
user> (.indexOf x 'Tier10)
1
user> (def y ['Tier20 'Tier10 'Tier30])
#'user/y
user> (reduce #(max %1 (.indexOf x %2)) y)
; Evaluation aborted.
user> (x (reduce #(max %1 (.indexOf x %2)) 0 y))
Tier30
user>
```

Naturally, this is O(n<sup>2</sup>). If you'll do this on a large scale, you'll be much better served by a hash-map from TierN to its ordering index.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is of `java.lang.String` then with a bit of interop:

```
user=> (def array ["Tier5" "Tier10" "Tier20" "Tier30" "Tier40" "Tier50"])
#'user/array
user=> (defn find-max [m] (reduce #(if (> (.compareTo %1 %2) -1) %1 %2) m))
#'user/find-max
user=> (find-max array)
"Tier50"
user=> (find-max "a")
\a
```

If not just make them implement `Comparable`, or create a  `Comparator`.

Comment: That list is just to define the ordering of each element. Given this ordering, I need to do something like `(find_max ["Tier20" "Tier10" "Tier30"])`